# How to toggle color of random sentences in a text in Meteor

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor

I have a text and several tags on my website and I want to highlight a random sentence every time I click a tag (at the same time, the tag become "active"). Here's my code:

```
'click #mytag .selectize-control.multi .selectize-input [data-value]': function(){
   if($(event.target).attr('class') == "item"){
        $(event.target).removeClass().addClass('item active');
        var dataval = $(event.target).attr('data-value');
        //to "deactivate" other active tags
        $('.selectize-control.multi .selectize-input [data-value]').each(function(){ 
         if($(this).attr('class') == "item active" && $(this).attr('data-value') != dataval){
             $(this).removeClass().addClass('item');
          }
        });

       //generate a random random index and find the corresponding sentence to change the color
       Meteor.call("generateSentence",asin, function(error, result){
          Session.set("colorSentence", result);
       }); 
       var sid = Session.get("colorSentence");
       var id = 'span#sentence'+sid.toString();
       $(id).css("background","yellow"); 
    }
  }
```

I can get a random sentence highlighted with a background color yellow every time i click on one tag. However, I want to toggle the color off next time i click another tag so that there's only one line with background color each time. Can anyone suggest how to do it?

Also, in order to only keep one tag "active" each time, I loop through all tags to check its status and turn other active ones off. It's pretty brute but at least works as my tags are too many. But as there're much more sentences here, I don't want to do the same thing here. I also appreciate any ideas about a cleverer way to deactivate other tags each time. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, add a `class="sentence"` to all your sentence spans.

Now, to deactivate your backgrounds, do

```
$('span.sentence').attr( style, '' );
```

Secondly, the way you are using Session variables to handle the result of the Meteor call is a bad pattern. It uses an unnecessary reactive observer and is harder to follow than doing the work in the callback. So in total, your code becomes:

```
Meteor.call( "generateSentence", asin, function(error, result){
   $( 'span.sentence' ).attr( style, '' );
   $( 'span#sentence' + result ).css( "background", "yellow" ); 
});
```

Replace your explicit loop to  deactivate your tags with jQuerys build in handling of multiple element selections, the same way as you clear the sentence styles.